# Spring Boot user is null in @AuthenticationPrincipal in Logout

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem about getting user entity values from the authenticated process.
After I sign in, I want to logout.

I have a problem to get authenticated user value as it is null.

I got this error when I logout

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.modal.User.getId()" because "this.user" is null
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my CurrentUser class shown below.

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {

}
```

Here is my AuthController class shown below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

UserService userService;

RoleService roleService;

RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

PasswordEncoder encoder;

JwtUtils jwtUtils;

@Autowired
public AuthController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService, RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService,
                      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder encoder, JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.roleService = roleService;
    this.refreshTokenService = refreshTokenService;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.encoder = encoder;
    this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
}

@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser is started");

        String username = loginRequest.getUsername();
        String password = loginRequest.getPassword();

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | username : " + username);
        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | password : " + password);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken : " + usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.toString());

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | jwt : " + jwt);

        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | roles : " + roles.toString());

        RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(userDetails.getId());

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | refreshToken : " + refreshToken.toString());

        JWTResponse jwtResponse = new JWTResponse();
        jwtResponse.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
        jwtResponse.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        jwtResponse.setId(userDetails.getId());
        jwtResponse.setToken(jwt);
        jwtResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshToken.getToken());
        jwtResponse.setRoles(roles);

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | authenticateUser | jwtResponse : " + jwtResponse.toString());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwtResponse);
    }

@PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser(@CurrentUser CustomUserDetails user) {

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | logoutUser is started");

        int userId = user.getId();

        int deletedValue = refreshTokenService.deleteByUserId(userId);

        if(deletedValue == 1){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Log out successful!"));
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("You're already logout"));
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my CustomDetails class shown below.

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authories = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Role role : roles) {
            authories.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()));
        }

        return authories;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return user.getId();
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return user.getEmail();
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomUserDetailsService class shown below.

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User Name " + username + " not found"));

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

Here is my WebSecurityConfig class shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;;

    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler,JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/pages/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(jwtUtils,customUserDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter(JwtUtils jwtUtils, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        return new AuthTokenFilter(jwtUtils, customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one change based on your repo : https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootRefreshTokenJWT

1. AuthController.java

```java
import java.security.Principal;
import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;
...
@PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser(@ApiIgnore Principal principalUser) {

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | logoutUser is started");

        //Since in AuthFilter You are setting UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, we will retrieve and cast
        Object principal = ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principalUser).getPrincipal();
        CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) principal;

        int userId = user.getId();

        int deletedValue = refreshTokenService.deleteByUserId(userId);

        if(deletedValue == 1){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Log out successful!"));
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("You're already logout"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Here is my repository. https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootRefreshTokenJWT I always get null user information.

Comment: Issue is: Your JWT token is expired before hitting logout endpoint. Can you check how you are generating and setting exp date properly?

Comment: jwt.secret.expireMs is 1 minute. After I sign in, I try to logout but I still get null value. It takes less than 1 minute but I get an error.

Comment: Yes. I got that. I have updated the answer, Only one change, It is working for me.

Comment: No problem.You can accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: How can I logout through Swagger Ui as it asks me name field? https://dosya.co/s0a0aa1pyah0/spring_boot_refresh_token_issues.PNG.html

Comment: That field is injected by spring and its to mandatory to come from the browser. You can hide that field. Not sure about that, but you can try this if it works for you. `public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser(@ApiIgnore Principal principalUser) {`  import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore

Comment: I mean that field is not mandatory

Comment: I'll try it. I'll inform you when it works.